# UITableView would not call the delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview

I try to package the UITableView as my own.
The code is:

```
@interface OPTableView : UIView<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *_dataSource;
    id<OPTableviewDelegate>_delegate;
}
@property(retain,nonatomic)id<OPTableviewDelegate>delegate;
@property(retain,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *dataSource;
```

.m:

```
@implementation OPTableView

@synthesize delegate=_delegate;
@synthesize dataSource=_dataSource;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        tableView.delegate=self;
        tableView.dataSource=self;
        _dataSource=[NSMutableArray array];
        [self addSubview:tableView];
        [tableView release];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma table delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tab didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

When I create OPTableView,it can show in the screen.But the problem is that when I did select one table,it would not call the delegate method :didSelectRowAtIndexPath,but what is worse,it breaks down.

Comment: What do you mean "It breaks down"? It crashes? If so, how? What message do you get? Help us help you.

Comment: Yes,it crashes.It just shows:0x110009b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi  .And the log shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your cell's selection style to some non-none value. Also note you should implement all the required delegate messages of your table - did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

What is OPTableViewDelegate? Your table's delegate is of type OPTableViewDelegate, not UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: I just want to tran the UITableViewDelegate to my OPTableViewDelegate,maybe you didn't see the code clearly.I just leave out some code.

Answer (score 0):

all,I have made a really stupid mistake.
In the 'initWithFrame' method,the code:_dataSource=[NSMutableArray array]; is absolutely wrong.

I delete this code"_dataSource=[NSMutableArray array]; ",everything works.

Thanks all.